# mysql database simple PK FK table design

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables, one is students, one is subjects. The tables look like this

```
students
- id (FK)
- name

subjects
- student_id (PK)
- math
- english
```

I don't understand one thing, why if I delete by student_id in subjects table, student's record is gone but not the other way round? I delete a student record, his subjects record is still there.

So how should I design my API?

I thought is `localhost/api/student/id <-- frontend` should pass me the id of the student, and I shall delete the record of their subject too, isn't it?

Comment: See this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat what you want me to know specifically?